# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function Dog() in Psy Shell code on line 1

Tags: laravel

I want to create a new instance, but I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Dog() in Psy Shell code on line 1

I tried:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Then:

```php
$dog = new App/Models/Dog();
```

But I always get the same error. I tried it with `out ()`, but then I got some warnings like:

```
<warning>PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant Models - assumed 'Models' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in Psy Shell code on line 1</warning>
<warning>PHP Notice:  Object of class Illuminate\Support\Facades\App could not be converted to number in Psy Shell code on line 1</warning>
<warning>PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in Psy Shell code on line 1</warning>
<warning>PHP Warning:  Division by zero in Psy Shell code on line 1</warning>
<warning>PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant Dog - assumed 'Dog' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in Psy Shell code on line 1</warning>
<warning>PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in Psy Shell code on line 1</warning>
<warning>PHP Warning:  Division by zero in Psy Shell code on line 1</warning>
```

Comment: Wrong slashes `new \App\Models\Dog()` instead of `new App/Models/Dog()`

Comment: Thanks man you're an genius i were trying now 1h to see what can be the problem